# How to check if a check box is already checked before I click on it

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am modifying a functionality in which save button should only get enabled if any pre-selected value get changed. For radio button I wrote  a blunder code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="allIB"style="vertical-align:middle;height:10px;width:15px;top:10px;" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this.id)">

<input type="radio" id="allOB" style="vertical-align:middle;height:10px;width:15px;top:10px;" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this.id)">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function enableSave1(id)
{
     abc=id;
     if(document.getElementById('abc').checked)
     {
        btnCommit.src='images\\Button\\Normal\\Save.gif';
        btnCommit.disabled=false;
     } 
 }
```

This is not working is there any way by which I can check if a radio button is already selected then clicking on it doesn't cause save button doesn't to get enabled.

Comment: So you want the button to be enabled only if a radio-input is checked? Or if a particular radio-input is checked?

Answer (score 0):

change your function as

```
function enableSave1(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        btnCommit.src = 'images\\Button\\Normal\\Save.gif';
        btnCommit.disabled = false;
    } else {
        btnCommit.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

or your code as

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="allIB" style="vertical-align:middle;height:10px;width:15px;top:10px;" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this)">

<input type="radio" id="allOB" style="vertical-align:middle;height:10px;width:15px;top:10px;" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this)">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function enableSave1(radio) {
    if (radio.checked) {
        btnCommit.src = 'images\\Button\\Normal\\Save.gif';
        btnCommit.disabled = false;
    } else {
        btnCommit.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the else part of the if condition to disable the button and also remove the '' around abc:

```
else{
btnCommit.disabled=true;
}
```